# Redirecting path to remote mount point

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I've got an NFS mount pointing at a different server:

```
mount -t nfs X.X.X.X:/asteriskstorage /mnt/asteriskstorage
```

I can access `/mnt/asteriskstorage` and all seems fine.

What I want to do is redirect the path `/var/spool/asterisk/monitor` to `/mnt/asteriskstorage`.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about a symlink, which of course will only work when the mount is active on the particular machine:

```
ln -s /mnt/asteriskstorage /var/spool/asterisk/monitor
```

Comment: Ok thanks - do I need to remove the local /var/spool/asterisk/monitor path first?

Comment: yep. rename it, for testing purposes. if something is not as you want, you may change it back..